# Multiple Forms on 1 Page Python FLASK

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

So I am loading all users from a database on a single page and I'm generating a password reset form for each user on the same page rather than having an individual page for each user.

My question is how can I click submit and apply the change for that specific user since I have multiple forms and submit buttons for each user via drop-down menu?

In my case the submit button is the "Reset Password" button.

[image]

I'm trying to call the form normally using

```
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
    password = request.form['password']
```

but I'm getting exception error

```
name 'form' is not defined
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while but i'm getting pretty confused now as I've got multiple forms (one per user) on the same page.

> NOTE : I'm not using WTForms for this task

Thanks

Comment: you use `request.form` and `form` in the above code (in `form.validate()`), presumably to refer to the same object, which implies one of them is wrong. The error seems like you want to change `form.validate()` to `request.form.validate()`. But, if your not using WTForms does the inherent form as part of a request have a validate method? I don't know but I suspect not.

Comment: Why not do a first treatment with javascript/jquery and then send the information to flask via ajax? it's less painful to the head I find! ... Curiosity: what tool do you use for your design?

Comment: @Attack68 thanks for your help... you were absolutely right. Actually my problem was that since I was not using WTForms for this one I didn't have the .validate() function. I removed the .validate() and it worked well......

Comment: @Tobin i'm using Bootstrap for this project as a skeleton, but I usually use Zurb foundation for grids and responsive views and custom CSS / HTML. I'm using bootstrap since I find it perfect for prototyping...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this one has been answered but here is what i just figured out:

After your standard

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

you can test for the existence of each form item within the request.form data. So add another if statement after the first

```
if 'my_form_element_name' in request.form:
    print ('stuff')
```

If you have other types of form data such as files, you can do something like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file_element_name' in request.files:
        return stuff
    elif 'my_form_element_name' in request.form:
           return stuff
    else: return stuff
else: return stuff
```

I have four forms in one html file and this method worked for me.